# How to solve this logic problem with status and picking?

Tags: logic

Background Job A

1. Picks a record and update the status as picked
2. It will process sequence of steps
3. Once everything is done, status is changed to complete
4. When there is an error encountered during the steps, status is changed to error

Another Job B does the following

1. Picks a record where the status is picked or error status
2. Process the sequence of steps

Job B - Reprocessing Job which handles the exception and system crash use case

Example,

Job A - When the application crashes some of the records will be left with status Picked

so inorder to handle the crash scenario and error scenario

Job B - looks for both picked and error status record

Issue:

Job A should take only the fresh records
Job A should handle the exception case and error case. Job B should not fetch the fresh records.

How to handle this situation?

Comment: difficult to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the time stamp here or check the date

Like
Job B should be only take yesterday or like previous hour timestamp record

So the fresh record are taken by job A and the previous hours which would be termed as old job would be taken by Job B